# Password Confirmation Directive

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-directive

Here is the code I'm using for the directive:

```
var compareTo = function() {
return {
  require: "ngModel",
  scope: {
    otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

    ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function(modelValue) {
        console.log(modelValue + ":" + scope.otherModelValue);
      return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
    };

    scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
      ngModel.$validate();
    });
  }
  };
};
app.directive("compareTo", compareTo);
```

Here is my html:

```
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <span>Must contain at least eight characters, including uppercase, lowercase letters and numbers</span>
            <input type="password" 
                class="form-control"
                name="password"
                ng-model="signUpPass1"
                ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/"
                required>
            <div ng-messages="signUpForm.password.$error" class="formMsgContainer">
                <span class="formMsg" ng-message="pattern">Passwords Does Not Meet the Criterias!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password"
            class="form-control"
            name="conPass"
            ng-model="signUpPass2"
            compare-to="signUpPass1"
            required>
            <div ng-messages="signUpForm.conPass.$error" class="formMsgContainer">
                <span class="formMsg" ng-message="compareTo">Passwords Do Not Match!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However the `compareTo` directive doesn't work. Looking at the console log I put in the directive, it prints out the string for pass2 and `undefined` for pass1. Such as `aaaa:undefined`. This means that they will never be equal and thus there will always be an error. So there must be something wrong with the statement `scope.otherModelValue` but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this directive. I haven't tested it, so if it doesn't work, please tell me.

```
app.directive("compareTo", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
      scope.$watch(attributes.ngModel, function(value) {
        controller.$setValidity('compare', (element.val() === value));
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You can then use the "compare" in the ng-message to output an error.

Comment: I did a test of it and it seems like element.val() and value are referring to the same thing. As when I console log them, whatever I put into the confirmation field gets printed twice. And it ignores what was inputed into the original password field.

Comment: Got it to work. Apparently declaring the scope variables in the controller was causing it. I'm not well versed with intricacies of angular so I'm not sure as to why this would cause the error. For example: $scope.signUpPass1 = "";

Answer (score 0):

To create your own checks try directive [use-form-error](https://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error). It is easy to use and will save you a lot of time.

Live example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/703qxbcg/)

```
 <form name="ExampleForm">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input ng-model="password" required />
  <br>
   <label>Confirm password</label>
  <input ng-model="confirmPassword" required />
  <div use-form-error="isSame" use-error-expression="password && confirmPassword && password!=confirmPassword" ng-show="ExampleForm.$error.isSame">Passwords Do Not Match!</div>
</form>
```